# How to find the class or type of the word?

Tags: nlp

Is there online knowledge bank or net, where we can find out what does any word depict? For example, briskly depicts how or manner, red is a colour, often means frequency etc?

Comment: Can you tell please why the -1?

Answer (score 1):

There is Datamuse, it can find similar words and words that sound similar. I created a java wrapper for their API: https://github.com/sjblair/Datamuse4J

Answer (score 0):

Try concept-net. It often provided the meaning of type of word.